# Show Multiple Size URL of one Featured Image/Thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

Is it possible to print two different url's from the same featured image/thumbnail?

So i have set up my image size..

```
add_image_size( 'full-size', 460, 9999 ); 
add_image_size('fixed-height', NULL, 75, false);
```

I need to pull the url of these two images sizes into the post like so..

```
<li><img src="full-size.jpg" ref="fixed-height.jpg" ></li>
```

Obviously i could not use the normal way..

```
<li><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('full-size'); ?>" ref="<?php the_post_thumbnail('fixed-height'); ?>" ></li>
```

Is it possible to do what i'm after, or no go?

Thanks for anyone that can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no problem to have 2 or more post thumbnails of different sizes.
but what is the "ref" attribute ? do you mean "rel" ?

anyhow - example from the  :[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

```
 <?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
   echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
   echo '</a>';
 }
 ?>
```

mind that `the_post_thumbnail()` will give you the full HTML for the image , to get other attributes, you will need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` or `get_post_thumbnail_id()` with  `wp_get_attachment_image_src`

```
    $fullsize = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'fullsize' );
    $fixed_height = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'fixed_height' ) ;
// returns array in which :
echo $fullsize[0] ;// url of fullsize 
echo $fixed_height[0] ;// url of fixed_height
```

Comment: Its for the image gallery http://www.pikachoose.com it requires ref. Thanks i've found a way using get_the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

I would combine [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) with [`get_intermediate_image_sizes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes), e.g.:

```
<?php
// globalize $post object
global $post;

// Get the array of registered image sizes
$image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

// Loop through the image sizes, and 
// use them to output the Featured Image
foreach ( $image_sizes as $image_size ) {
    echo '<li>';
    the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $image_size );
    echo '</li>';
}

?>
```

Note: I don't think `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` sorts the array of image sizes, so you may need to manipulate the return value, if you want to output the images ordered by size.